# work with te same array on every roure function on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
const path = require('path');
const config = require('./config/config.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = mongoose.connection;
const session = require('express-session')
const flash = require('express-flash');
const User = require('./models/user');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const loginController = require('./controllers/loginController');
const profileController = require('./controllers/profileController');
const testController = require('./controllers/testController');
const gameController = require('./controllers/gameController');
const registerController = require('./controllers/registerController');
const mainPageController = require('./controllers/mainPageController');
const isAuthenticated = require('./middleware/isAuthenticated');
require('./passport/passport_config');

app.use(session({
  secret: config.session_secret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist'));
app.use(flash());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

var connected = [];

mongoose.connect( config.db_connect, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true
});

//conexión a la bd
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('Database successfull connection!!');
    http.listen(config.port, () => {
        console.log(`ChatLearning app listening at http://localhost:${config.port}`)
    })
});

//rutas
app.get('/', isAuthenticated, mainPageController.showMainPage);
app.get('/logout', mainPageController.logout);

app.get('/login', loginController.login);
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate( 
        'local-signin', 
        { 
            successRedirect: '/',
            failureRedirect: '/login',
            failureFlash: true,
            badRequestMessage:'El usuario o contraseña utilizados no son correctos'
        }
    )
);
app.get('/registro', registerController.register);
app.post('/registro', registerController.registerUser);

app.get('/google-signin',
  passport.authenticate('google', 
    { scope:[ 'email', 'profile' ]}
));

app.get( '/google-callback',
    passport.authenticate( 'google', 
        {
            successRedirect: '/',
            failureRedirect: '/failure'
        }
    )
);

app.get('/perfil',isAuthenticated, profileController.showProfile);
app.post('/guardar-test', testController.saveTest);
app.get('/crear-test', isAuthenticated, testController.createTest);
app.get('/realizar-test',gameController.startGame);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

I have an array called connected
`var connected = [];`

and I need to use the same array  in the route functions that are located on other files as

```
const User = require('../models/user')

login = function (req,res){
    let messages = { 'error':req.flash('error') };
    res.render('login/login.twig', messages);   
}

module.exports = {login}
```

How could I use connected array on login function without using classes?Maybe its no the correct approach and I need to uses classes and pass the array on a setter function

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

connected.js

```
var connected = []

module.exports = {
  connected
}
```

someroute.js

```
const { connected } = require('./connected')
...
```